# Property does not exist on type 'T' - Generic problems

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types

I have a util that takes an array and a predicate to perform a filtration of the array, however after using my custom type for the predicate I am getting an error stating

> property 'name' does not exist on type 'T'

I thought that the generic property type `T` would have accepted anything?

Am I missing something obvious?

**Array.ts**

```
export type arrayPredicate = <T>(arg: T) => boolean;
```

**ArrayUtil**

```
static filterArray<T>(array: T[], arrayPred: arrayPredicate): T {
    const key =  Object.keys(array).find(obj => arrayPred(array[obj]));
    return array[key];
  }
```

**Usage in test**

```
const array = [
  {
    'name': 'object-1',
    'id': 1
  },
  {
    'name': 'object-2',
    'id': 2
  }
];

it(... , () => {

  // I get red squigglies under '.name'

  const myObj = ArrayUtils.filterArray(exceptionalStatuses, 
                                          (status => status.name === findStatus));

  ...

});
```

Of course, changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your arrayPredicate declaration as shown below.

```
export type arrayPredicate<T> = (arg: T) => boolean;

class ArrayUtils {
    static filterArray<T>(array: T[], arrayPred: arrayPredicate<T>): T {
    const key =  Object.keys(array).find(obj => arrayPred(array[obj]));
    return array[key];
  }
}
```

Since you are not declaring parameter in type for arrayPredicate, it is assumed to be empty object.

Here is working example,

[TypeScript example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20type%20arrayPredicate%3CT%3E%20%3D%20(arg%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ArrayUtils%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20filterArray%3CT%3E(array%3A%20T%5B%5D%2C%20arrayPred%3A%20arrayPredicate%3CT%3E)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20key%20%3D%20%20Object.keys(array).find(obj%20%3D%3E%20arrayPred(array%5Bobj%5D))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20array%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20array%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'name'%3A%20'object-1'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'id'%3A%201%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'name'%3A%20'object-2'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'id'%3A%202%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AArrayUtils.filterArray(array%2C%20(status%20%3D%3E%20status.name%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22a%22))%3B)

Comment: Ah amazing! Who'd have thought changing where the <T> in the predicate was declared would have such a profound impact?!

Comment: @physicsboy TypeScript doesn't force generic argument, so in absence of generic argument, it assumes argument to be an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add a type for your array for exmaple lets sat type of the array is `SampleType[]`. Then is should be

```
const array: SampleType[] = [
  {
    'name': 'object-1',
    'id': 1
  },
  {
    'name': 'object-2',
    'id': 2
  }
];
```

Then pass that type to the generic function

```
 ArrayUtils.filterArray<SampleType>(exceptionalStatuses, (status: SampleType => status.name === findStatus));
```

SampleType should be

```
export class SampleType{
  name: string,
  id: string
}
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add that my array does actually already have a type. I applied changes based on what you suggested, but I am still getting the same error :-/

Comment: I think I have found my problem. The `.name` property isn't actually available in my `type` for some reason. I will investigate and update here if I find any more info...